# How to fix wamp server don't work localhost refused to connect?

Tags: wamp, wampserver

I have a wampserver version 2.3 X86 icon go to green but when write localhost or 127.0.0.0 appear localhost refused to connect.
appear in the image below:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EWzoY.jpg)

How to fix it?

Comment: you are running wamp on which port?

Comment: What is in your HOSTS file?

Comment: running in port 80 change to 8080 but don't work.

Comment: @RiggsFolly what do you mean?

Comment: Please show us the contents of `C:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts`

Comment: Does the silence mean that you looked at and fixed your HOSTS file?

Comment: i have this same weird issue, sometimes it work but most of the time, i get localhost refused to connect

Answer (score 0):

I think your service is off. Turn on your service.

Go To - `My Computer->Manage->Service and Application->Services->here find your server and restart service`.

This will work for you.